# Instalar bokeh 0.13.0 en Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, bokeh

He tratado de instalar esta versión de bokeh para ubuntu, pero sin resultados. Primeramente, bajé el tar.gz direcamente del repositorio github de bokeh:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/releases/tag/0.13.0

pero al ejecutar el comando ./configure sale:
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Entonces traté también de convertir el tar en .deb a través de "alien", y sin ningún resultado.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué intentas instalarlo como un módulo del OS, siendo que quien mantiene ese paquete dice **explícitamente** que se debe instalar:

> enter the following command at a Bash or Windows command prompt:
>
> `conda install bokeh`
>
> To install using pip, enter the following command at a Bash or Windows command prompt:
>
> `pip install bokeh`

Es un módulo Python, así que no se va a instalar como un paquete del OS, sin importar el manejador de paquetes que intentes. Siempre es ideal que leas el README que pone quien mantiene un código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]